# ¿Cómo agrego evento a botón cargado por AJAX?

Tags: javascript, api

Tengo el siguiente problema

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Estoy consumiendo una API de películas, en donde al principio solo carga el buscador, una vez que se busca algo, con un *foreach* los agrego a resultados, cada uno tiene un ID específico.

Lo que deseo es con el evento clic capturar lo que aloje con el atributo *target* de cada resultado y así buscar información extra, como actores etc.

Pero al dar clic no hace nada y me tira que el evento es nulo. Puse todos los script al último y hasta usé `window.onload`

En la interfaz:

```
peliculasAPI.forEach(pelicula => {
        this.listado.innerHTML += 
    
        `<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mt-5 pt-5">
            <div class="card m-0">
                <img src="${pelicula.Poster}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> <strong>${pelicula.Title}</strong></h5>
                    <span class="d-block mb-2 card-text badge badge-primary text-wrap"><strong ">Category</strong>: ${pelicula.Type}</span>
                    <span class="d-block card-text badge badge-primary text-wrap"><strong ">Year</strong>: ${pelicula.Year}</span>
                    <button id="btn-seeMore" target="${pelicula.imdbID}" class="text-center mt-3 ">See more</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`                                   
    });
```

Cuando asigno el evento:

```
const valorBtn = document.getElementById("btn-seeMore");
    valorBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        console.log(e.target);
      
   });
```

Comment: Lo que añadas con `innerHTML` no es parte del `DOM`. Deberías agregar los elementos mediante `appendChild` o algún otro método que efectivamente actualice el `DOM`. Saludos

Comment: Otro problema es que estas duplicando el id `btn-seeMore` en el loop. Los `id` deberian ser unicos.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, lo que cargas con `innerHTML` sí forma parte del DOM, aunque puede que al navegador le tome un poco de tiempo interpretarlo; el problema real es que el contenido se va agregando y no existe todavía cuando él intenta acceder.

Answer (score 0):

He testeado la propiedad innerHTML y si puedes registrar un evento.
Imagino que en tu caso no funciona, quizas algun error de script al llamar a los tag ${} embedidos o quizas intentando ejecutar el JS antes que cargue por completo el DOM.
O que intentes registrar el evento antes de llamar a innerHTML.

En el siguiente ejemplo he copiado el codigo html sin los tag ${}.
He creado un div donde mostraria el contenido usando innerHTML.

```js
 document.getElementById("midiv").innerHTML += `<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mt-5 pt-5">
                <div class="card m-0">
                    <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"> <strong></strong></h5>
                        <span class="d-block mb-2 card-text badge badge-primary text-wrap"><strong ">Category</strong>: </span>
                        <span class="d-block card-text badge badge-primary text-wrap"><strong ">Year</strong>:</span>
                        <button id="btn-seeMore" target="" class="text-center mt-3 ">See more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`
            
var btn = document.getElementById("btn-seeMore");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<div id="midiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como estás agregando el contenido, no es posible acceder a elementos que aún no existen y, de paso, estás repitiendo ID de botón; es mejor agregar `btn-seeMore` a la lista de clases.

Para este ejemplo, el botón *Agregar* y la función `agrega()` simularán la carga de contenido por AJAX y lo único que va a cambiar en cada llamada es el número, solo para poder identificar dónde se hizo clic.

Como aún no hay botones, no puedes asignarles evento, pero sí puedes asignarlo al documento, obteniendo el objeto que recibió clic con `event.target` y, si contiene la clase `btn-seeMore`, llamar a la función donde controlas las acciones del botón.

Para obtener el valor de un atributo no estándar (o personalizado) es necesario usar `elemento.getAttribute('nombre-de-atributo')`:

```js
let contador = 1;
function agrega() {
    listado.innerHTML += 
            `<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mt-5 pt-5">
                <div class="card m-0">
                    <img src="Poster ${contador}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Título ${contador}</strong></h5>
                        <span class="d-block mb-2 card-text badge badge-primary text-wrap"><strong ">Category</strong>: Topo ${contador}</span>
                        <span class="d-block card-text badge badge-primary text-wrap"><strong ">Year</strong>: Año ${contador}</span>
                        <button target="Target ${contador}" class="text-center mt-3 btn-seeMore">See more</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
    // Actualizar contador para identificar los elementos agregados
    contador ++;
}
// Recibe como parámetro el botón donde se hizo clic
function seeMore(button) {
    // Obtener atributo personalizado
    console.log(button.getAttribute('target'));
}
// Ejecutar hasta que el DOM se haya cargado
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#btn-add').addEventListener('click', agrega);
    // Evento onclick para el documento
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // El clic fue en un botón con clase btn-seeMore?
        if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-seeMore')) {
            // Ejecutar función, enviando el botón que recibió el clic
            seeMore(e.target);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="listado"></div>
<button id="btn-add">Agregar</button>
```